# separating strings by some text within listbox

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I have a `ListBox` where table names are written like this:

```
Staging_Section_01_2019_03_19_01  
Staging_Section_01_2019_03_20_01  
Staging_Section_23_2019_03_21_01  
Staging_Section_52_2019_03_23_01  
Staging_Section_52_2019_03_24_01
```

What I am trying to do is to separate them by Section Number, so I want all `Section_01` in one `List` object and `Section_23` in another `List` object, so on and so forth. The dynamic nature is whats making it difficult for me.

So far, I have the following:

```
foreach (var it in uploadBox.Items)
{
    if (it.ToString().Contains("Section"))
    {
        section = it.ToString().Substring(0, 18);
        found = it.ToString().IndexOf("_");
        section = section.Substring(found + 1);
        sectionNum = section.Substring(8, 2);
    }
}
```

I have gotten the `sectionNum` which would just be the number and section, which is the string like `Section_01`.

Any idea on how to approach this?

The expected output would be something like this:

#### List 1

```
Staging_Section_01_2019_03_19_01  
Staging_Section_01_2019_03_20_01
```

#### List 2

```
Staging_Section_23_2019_03_21_01
```

#### List 3

```
Staging_Section_52_2019_03_23_01  
Staging_Section_52_2019_03_24_01
```

Comment: This looks like a great fit for regular expressions.

Comment: I think the op's question is how to put them is separate lists by their number.

Comment: Please show us an example of what is your expected output

Comment: And, is it possible to have a _Section_100_ or a _Section_1000_?

Comment: is it always Staging_Section_##?. If so, just store the current one and on the next loop if that substring is not the same as your stored one, create a new list and add the current one. Each time saving to ensure that you are comparing the previous for a change.

Comment: @Steve no it will remain below 100 sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` for this. Each 'section' that is parsed would be a key, and the remaining portion would the the value.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var it in uploadBox.Items)
{
    if (it.ToString().Contains("Section"))
    {
        section = it.ToString().Substring(0, 18);
        found = it.ToString().IndexOf("_");
        section = section.Substring(found + 1);
        sectionNum = section.Substring(8, 2);

        if(!myDict.ContainsKey(sectionNum))
        {
            myDict.Add(sectionNum, new List<string> { someOtherValue });
        }
        else
        {
            myDict[sectionNum].Add(someOtherValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Unless I have completely misinterpreted your question, I think this is a potential solution to your dynamic objects.

Comment: That Substring(0,18) will be a problem if we have a _...Section_100..._

Comment: I agree. I'd recommend splitting on '_' and just joining index 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
var sections = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach(var it in uploadBox.Items)
{
    var item = it.ToString();

    if(item.Contains("Section"))
    {

        var section = GetSection(item);

        if(!sections.ContainsKey(section))
        {
            sections.Add(section, new List<string>());            
        } 

        sections[section].Add(item);
    }    
}

private string GetSection(string item)
{
    var split = item.Split("_");
    return $"{split[1]}_{split[2]}";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to regex for this kind of task:

```
uploadBox.Items
    .GroupBy(x => Regex.Match(x.ToString(), @"^\w+_Section_(?<section>\d+)").Groups["section"].Value)
```